# Algebraic equivalent of the metric tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

Given a smooth manifold $M$, it is known that there is a canonical bijection between $M$ and the maximal ideals of $C^\infty(M, \mathbb{R})$ that have residue field $\mathbb{R}$. The ideal corresponding to a point $p\in M$ is simply the set of functions that vanish at $p$. This is a deep link between differential topology and algebraic geometry. For instance, the differential tangent space $T_p M$ is isomorphic to the Zariski tangent space of Spec $C^\infty(M, \mathbb{R})$, at the corresponding ideal.

However, in order to upgrade to differential geometry, we need extra structures such as affine connections and metric tensors. Do those have equivalent structures in algebraic geometry? I know there are flat modules, but I doubt they relate to manifolds with zero curvature.

Comment: The naive thought is that if $\mathcal{I}_p$ is the ideal you define, then $\mathcal{I}_p/\mathcal{I}_p^2$ is the cotangent space at $p$. A Riemannian metric would be an inner product on this vector space for each $p \in M$. There's probably a shieaf theoretic way to formulate this. Maybe using the sheaf of sections of $T^*M\otimes T^*M$?

The other thought is that a standard tool used in complex algebraic geometry is the Kahler metric. Any chance you now how that is defined in sheaf theoretic terms?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19308/is-there-an-analogue-of-curvature-in-algebraic-geometry

Comment: I don't know but you can check out Nestruev: https://www.amazon.com/Smooth-Manifolds-Observables-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/1441930477